# Default launcher not launching when press back

Tags: android, launcher

i am developing a launcher app but I am getting a problem when I am switching application from one two other and press back then it redirects me to system launcher.

my launcher is already a default launcher.

I am stuck in one problem whenever I open other application and press back then it's working ok but if I open the application and press recent apps button and after when I press back it redirects me to system launcher

[output](https://i.imgur.com/CTZlEhZ.gifv)

my code for opening clock app

```
try{
        Intent mClockIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
        mClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(mClockIntent);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        showToast("application not found");
    }
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo_bg"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper" />
        <!--android:excludeFromRecents="true"-->

        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.AppListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.PinActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.SettingActivity"
            android:label="Settings" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please suggest me, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your home activity as below, and set as the default launcher in Settings.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.rayvatapps.officelauncher.PinActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Error running 'app': Default Activity not found

Comment: @ChiragPatel could use "Specified Activity", or use "adb install -r xxx.apk" and then lunch your activity via "adb shell am start -n com.rayvatapps.officelauncher/.PinActivity".

Comment: still same issue when pressing back

Comment: Please set your activity as default home launcher in Settings.

Comment: did you test on other devices, not run the miui rom? if you don't have other devices, could use Genymotion to run an AOSP simulator.

Comment: I tested in Motorola g4 plus, redmi 5A and nexus emulator but  getting same output in all device